# How to improve: Navigating through multiple URLs with Python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I'm trying to navigate to multiple pages and download PDFs off of each one. The pages are hosted by the same site, just different URLs so the xpaths to download are all the same. The current code I have works, but I am a Python beginner and I'm sure there's an easier way to consolidate it - just having trouble figuring out how!

I have tried using a for loop but getting some errors.

This is what I am using now:

```
one ='urlone'
two = 'urltwo'
three = 'urlthree'

try:
    download = "C:/pathtodownload"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver.exe', chrome_options=options)

    driver.get(one)
    driver.maximize_window()
    actions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathhere')
    actions.click()
    time.sleep(4)

    driver.get(two)
    driver.maximize_window()
    actions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathhere')
    actions.click()
    time.sleep(4)

    driver.get(three)
    driver.maximize_window()
    actions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathhere')
    actions.click()
    time.sleep(4)

finally:
   driver.quit
```

I believe I should be able to do something like this, but I'm receiving an error. WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'url' must be a string

```
urls = ['urlone', 'urltwo', 'urlthree']

try:
    download = "C:/pathtodownload"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver.exe', chrome_options=options)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(urls)
    driver.maximize_window()
    actions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathhere')
    actions.click()
    time.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error.

```
urls = ['urlone', 'urltwo', 'urlthree']

try:
    download = "C:/pathtodownload"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver.exe', chrome_options=options)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url) # Here I changed urls that you used in your code to url
    driver.maximize_window()
    actions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpathhere')
    actions.click()
    time.sleep(4)
```

Basically using urls in the commented line you were trying to feed the whole urls list in the .get() method that only accepts a string.

Comment: @Johnathan
No worries, it happens to everyone to overlook a small detail that makes a total difference.
When you run into this kind of issues I suggest you to print your variables to the console in order to understand better what is going on or, if you have a good IDE (PyCharm or similar) use the debugger.
If you found the answer useful please remember to upvote it / mark it as resolution.

Have fun!